# Can an oozie coordinator rerun by skipping some actions

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

Can we rerun an oozie co-ordinator by skipping some nodes? I know we can do it in oozie workflow, but can we do it in co-ordinator as well?

Comment: can you give a use case or the same?

Comment: I have a co-ordinator which got succeeded for 100 actions. I realized that my actions from 50-60 were wrong and I want to re-execute 50-60 actions by skipping some of the actions which are not needed for rerun. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use the `oozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes` property to specify the actions which are completed previously. But they must be completed successfully. Try it out.

Comment: oozie.wf.rereun.skip.nodes is working only to restart a workflow but not a co-ordinator action. I will try again. Thank you @YoungHobbit

Answer (score 0):

You can re-run coordinator action or multi action as describe [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Rerunning_a_Coordinator_Action_or_Multiple_Actions)
Note that this will happen only for this run

But not sure this is recommended depending on the use case

Comment: yes I agree, in my rerun, I tried providing some rerun options like skip some nodes in an action using oozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes parameter which was not considered by oozie.